# Outlook keeps trying to add my licensee account as an email

Tags: microsoft-outlook

As of a couple weeks ago, the Outlook desktop program (installed from Office365) keeps complaining that it couldn't find a work or school account matching my personal hotmail address. Thing is, I don't even have my hotmail set up as an account in Outlook. Nor did I click any button to "Add a service". This happens once on start-up, every time I open Outlook.

[image]

a) I'm very confused why it's complaining about an account it's not configured for.

b) How can I get it to stop??

This hotmail account is the one linked to the subscription from which Office is downloaded and installed. I've verified that the subscription is paid-up, active and current. I do **not** get any such dialog when opening any other application installed from the subscription, such as Word, Excel, etc.

Running on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: This Hotmail account, is it linked to the Microsoft Account. that is subscribed to Office 365?

Comment: @Ramhound - yes, it is. I've verified that the account subscription is paid up, active and current.

Comment: So that is the reason Outlook is attempting to log into that Hotmail account. The reason it's failing is of course the fact, your Hotmail account, isn't a school or work account

Comment: Yeah but Outlook IS connected to the account for licensing fine. If I look in the about dialogs, it shows it's properly licensed and all. Why would it be trying to connect to it as an email account specifically if I haven't configured it to connect to that email account? I've NEVER had my hotmail account configured as an email account in Outlook, and it never did this before a couple weeks ago. (I've been using it for years on this Office365 subscription.)

Comment: Check again, next to the licensing stuff: is there any account with a warning or something? The dialog you see is not about mail accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook for individuals (as distinct from a business exchange server) is best managed at the account level in Control Panel, Mail.

Go there and delete the account and then if you wish the data file.

I use this and it works.

[image: Outlook Mail manangement]

.

If the above does not work for some reason, back up your email (be certain), delete the Outlook Profile (same place as in my screenshot, restart, and make a new Outlook profile.

If you do not have the accounts, and then you make a new Profile, then the non-existent hotmail account in Outlook will be gone.

That also works.  Proceed carefully.

Comment: That just launches the same dialog as from in Outlook, showing the same two accounts configured.

Comment: Look in the data files to see if there is a hotmail file..  You may need to back up your email. and delete the Outlook Profile. Then remake it.  I added this to my answer

Comment: Nope. There are no hotmail files in the data files.

Comment: As I noted in my answer, try remaking the Outlook Profile

Comment: Why have you not tried a new Outlook Profile?

Comment: Creating a new outlook profile seems to have done it. Guess MS must've frakked something up in the profile with an O365 update or something. I've never had to touch that control panel applet before in 26 years of working in IT.

Comment: Great!  Good to know Outlook is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Windows settings > Accounts > Access Work or School > Disconnect your email account. Restart your device.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It is much more likely a broken Outlook profile causing this. I have asked the author two or three times to re-create the Outlook Profile